# How can I remove the entire line after removing string with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex in Python to remove specific strings from a file; however, I also want it to delete the whole line after the string is removed and push everything up
For example:
Before regex:

```
apples
oranges
strawberries
```

When I run say

```
s = 'oranges'
r = re.compile(r"\s(?<!\n){0}.*".format(s), re.M)
txt_file = r.sub("", txt_file)
```

It becomes

```
apples

strawberries
```

But I want it to become

```
apples
strawberries
```

How could I accomplish this line removing after regex string removal? I've tried adding `.*` at the end of the regex expression but no luck.

Comment: have you tried s='oranges\n' so that it removes the carriage return too? '\n' is carriage return for Mac and Unix.

Comment: `re.compile(r"\s(?<!\n){0}.*[\r\n]+".format(s))`

Comment: @anubhava thank you that worked! anyway to prevent the tabbing of the next line after the removal?

Comment: `\s(?<!\n)` is better written as `[^\S\n]` - any whitespace but `\n`. Also, you need `[\r\n]*`, not `[\r\n]+`, or you won't get the match on the last line. Try `re.compile(r"[^\S\n]{}.*[\r\n]*".format(s))` or `re.compile(r"[^\S\n]{}.*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(s))`. Actually, it is not clear why you use `\s(?<!\n)`, your examples show no whitespace before the keywords. If you need to match a word after a space or start of string/line, you may use `re.compile(r"(?<!\S){}.*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(s))`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/kOoq3C

Comment: SooWoo, if you need a definitive answer please explain what you mean by "prevent tabbing of the next line after removal", or just let @anubhava post his answer, remove that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<!\S){}.*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(re.escape(s))
```

Note you need to escape the dynamic variable to be used in a regex pattern safely.

It matches:

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- s - your `s` variable
- `.*` - 0+ chars up to the line end
- `(?:[\r\n]\s*)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches an optional sequence of

  - `[\r\n]` - a CR or LF symbol
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kOoq3C):

```
import re
txt_file = r"""apples
oranges
strawberries"""

s = 'oranges'
r = re.compile(r"(?<!\S){}.*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(s))
txt_file = r.sub("", txt_file)
print(txt_file)
```

Output:

```
apples
strawberries
```